# How to roll on an o

Tags: voice

Often during a song, some singers with almost no air in their voices, sort of roll on their o's, switching from one note to another without a break. Listen to the video below on 0:11. How can I possibly manage that?

YouTube Video: [Highasakite - Leaving No Traces (Live from Rockefeller, Oslo)](https://youtu.be/fVHLXEIGBXA).

Another example is what she is doing here, at 4:02. Instead of just switching note, she rolls over from one note to the other. She often does it when she’s making an ‘O’- sound.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a [melisma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melisma#Prevalence_in_popular_music_(mid_1980s_to_late_2000s)).  The most reliable way to learn how to sing melismas is from a teacher who can hear *you* try it.  But googling "how to sing a melisma" offers much advice as well.